# Generic XSLT to do XML to CSV - almost there, but stuck

Tags: xslt

I have gathered bits and pieces of this XSLT from these forums.  I'm trying to put them altogether to create a single, generic XSLT that can be used to convert XML to CSV by specifying the path to the nodes that should be included in the CSV file.

I have three things that I still can't figure out after about 10 hours of messing with it.

1. I want to iterate over each *column* named in *csv:columns*.  During each iteration, I need to extract and store the text() of the *column*.  I think this is the way to iterate, but want to make sure:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
   ```
2. Once I have the text() from the *column*, I need to put that into the *columnname* variable in such a way that it works when it is used with *getNodeValue*.

I was unable to set *columnname* using variable.  If I didn't hard-code the value (surrounded by apostrophes), I could not get it to work.  This is why I have the following line in the code:

```
     <xsl:variable name="columnname" select="'location/city'" />
```

3. I want to pass the result of *getNodeValue* into *quotevalue* so that the result is properly quoted.

The XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xpath-default-namespace="http://nowhere/" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','" />

<csv:columns>
    <column>title</column>
    <column>location/city</column>
</csv:columns>

<xsl:template match="job">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(@id, ',')"/>

   <!-- #1 I WANT TO LOOP THROUGH ALL OF THE CSV COLUMNS HERE -->

   <!-- #2 How do I put the text into the variable 'columnname' variable so that it works with getNodeValue? -->
   <xsl:variable name="columnname" select="'location/city'" />
   <xsl:variable name="vXpathExpression" select="$columnname"/>

   <xsl:call-template name="getNodeValue">
       <xsl:with-param name="pExpression" select="$vXpathExpression"/>
   </xsl:call-template>

   <!-- #3 After getNodeValue gets the value, I want to send that value into 'quotevalue' -->

   <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getNodeValue">
  <xsl:param name="pExpression"/>
  <xsl:param name="pCurrentNode" select="."/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(contains($pExpression, '/'))">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pCurrentNode/*[name()=$pExpression]"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:call-template name="getNodeValue">
       <xsl:with-param name="pExpression"
         select="substring-after($pExpression, '/')"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pCurrentNode" select=
       "$pCurrentNode/*[name()=substring-before($pExpression, '/')]"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="quotevalue">
   <xsl:param name="value"/>
   <xsl:choose>
   <!-- Quote the value if required -->
       <xsl:when test="contains($value, '&quot;')">
           <xsl:variable name="x" select="replace($value, '&quot;',  '&quot;&quot;')"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $x, '&quot;')"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="contains($value, $delimiter)">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $value, '&quot;')"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<positionfeed
   xmlns="http://nowhere/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2006-04">
   <job id="2830302">
       <employer>Acme</employer>
       <title>Manager</title>
       <description>Full time</description>
       <postingdate>2016-09-15T23:12:13Z</postingdate>
       <location>
          <city>Los Angeles</city>
          <state>California</state>
       </location>
    </job>
    <job id="2830303">
       <employer>Acme</employer>
       <title>Clerk, evenings</title>
       <description>Part time</description>
       <postingdate>2016-09-15T23:12:13Z</postingdate>
       <location>
          <city>Albany</city>
          <state>New York</state>
       </location>
    </job>
</positionfeed>
```

The current output using the XSLT I provided

```
2830302,Los Angeles
2830303,Albany
```

The output if the XSLT works as desired

```
2830302,Manager,Los Angeles
2830303,"Clerk, evenings",Albany
```

**Solution (many thanks to Tim's help below)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.job-search-engine.com/add-jobs/positionfeed-namespace/" >

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Set the value of the delimiter character -->
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','" />

    <!-- The name of the node that contains the column values -->
    <xsl:param name="containerNodeName" select="'job'"/>

    <!-- All nodes that should be ignored during processing -->
    <xsl:template match="source|feeddate"/>

    <!-- The names of the nodes to be included in the CSV file -->
    <xsl:variable name="columns" as="element()*">
       <column header="Title">title</column>
       <column header="Category">category</column>
       <column header="Description">description</column>
       <column header="PostingDate">postingdate</column>
       <column header="URL">joburl</column>
       <column header="City">location/city</column>
       <column header="State">location/state</column>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- ************** DO NOT TOUCH BELOW **************** -->
    <!-- ************** DO NOT TOUCH BELOW **************** -->
    <!-- ************** DO NOT TOUCH BELOW **************** -->
    <!-- ************** DO NOT TOUCH BELOW **************** -->
    <!-- ************** DO NOT TOUCH BELOW **************** -->

    <!-- Warn about unmatched nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:message terminate="no">
          <xsl:text>WARNING: Unmatched element: </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
       </xsl:message>

       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Generate the column headers -->
    <xsl:template match="//*[*[local-name()=$containerNodeName]]">
       <xsl:value-of select="'Id'"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
       <xsl:for-each select="$columns/@header">
       <xsl:variable name="colname" select="." />
           <xsl:value-of select="$colname"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Generate the rows of column data -->
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()=$containerNodeName]">

       <!-- TODO: Handle attributes generically -->
       <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>

       <xsl:variable name="container" select="." />
       <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
           <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
           <xsl:variable name="vXpathExpression" select="."/>
           <xsl:call-template name="getQuotedNodeValue">
               <xsl:with-param name="pCurrentNode" select="$container"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pExpression" select="$vXpathExpression"/>
           </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getQuotedNodeValue">
      <xsl:param name="pExpression"/>
      <xsl:param name="pCurrentNode" select="."/>

      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="not(contains($pExpression, '/'))">
         <xsl:variable name="result" select="$pCurrentNode/*[name()=$pExpression]"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="quotevalue">
           <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$result"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:call-template name="getQuotedNodeValue">
           <xsl:with-param name="pExpression" select="substring-after($pExpression, '/')"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pCurrentNode" select= "$pCurrentNode/*[name()=substring-before($pExpression, '/')]"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="quotevalue">
       <xsl:param name="value"/>
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="contains($value, '&quot;')">
               <!-- Quote the value and escape the double-quotes -->
               <xsl:variable name="x" select="replace($value, '&quot;',  '&quot;&quot;')"/>
               <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $x, '&quot;')"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Quote the value -->
               <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $value, '&quot;')"/>
           </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample data to demonstrate solution**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<positionfeed
    xmlns="http://www.job-search-engine.com/add-jobs/positionfeed-namespace/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.job-search-engine.com/add-jobs/positionfeed-namespace/ http://www.job-search-engine.com/add-jobs/positionfeed.xsd"
    version="2006-04">
<source>Casting360</source>
<feeddate>2016-11-11T21:48:34Z</feeddate><job id="1363612">
<employer>Casting360</employer>
<title>The Robert Irvine Show Is Seeking Guests</title>
<category>Reality TV</category>
<description>TV personality ROBERT IRVINE (Restaurant Impossible) is seeking guests looking for solutions to their unique problems to share their stories on his show!

Our next show is Thursday, September 22nd in LA. If you're not in LA we will provide your airfare, hotel, car service, and per diem. 

Please note: WE ARE NOT LOOKING FOR RESUMES; THIS IS NOT AN ACTING GIG. We are looking for real people to share their stories!

*appearance fee (TBD)

If you or someone you know has a conflict that they need help resolving, WE WANT TO HEAR FROM YOU. 

Please email tvgal.ri@gmail.com the following information:
Name
Phone number
Your story in 2-3 paragraphs
1-3 photos of yourself.</description>
<postingdate>2016-09-15T23:12:13Z</postingdate>
<joburl>http://casting360.com/lgj/8886644624?jobid=1363612&amp;city=Los+Angeles&amp;state=CA</joburl>
<location>
<nation>USA</nation>
<city>Los Angeles</city>
<state>California</state>
</location>
<jobsource>Casting360</jobsource>
</job><job id="1370302">
<employer>Casting360</employer>
<title>Photoshoot for Publication</title>
<category>Modeling</category>
<description>6 FEMALE Models are wanted for publication photoshoot.

If you're not in the NYC Vicinity (NY, Pa, Ct,) DO NOT REPLY because your response will be summarily ignored.

Chosen models will be given a 5 look photo shoot. The shoot will occur on location (outdoors) in highly public locations chosen both for it's convenience and scenery.

The 5 looks (outfits) will be pre-determined by our staff of items most outfits within a model's wardrobe. 

THIS IS A TF (UNPAID) SHOOT.  After the release of the magazine, the photos agreed upon from the shoot shall be given to the model (in digital format) for her to build her portfolio. 

Chosen models will receive a 5 outfit photo shoot at no cost to them by a NY Fashion Photographer.As a result, chosen  models not only receive a free photo shoot, but also become PUBLISHED MODELS featured in a magazine. 
The model (Janeykay) centered in the photo attached (Please look at the attached photo) is a Casting360 member who not only received her photo shoot, not only is being featured in a magazine, but also made the cover becoming a Cover Model from her shoot with us.</description>
<postingdate>2016-10-03T00:34:43Z</postingdate>
<joburl>http://casting360.com/lgj/8886644624?jobid=1370302&amp;city=New+York&amp;state=NY</joburl>
<location>
<nation>USA</nation>
<city>New York</city>
<state>New York</state>
</location>
<jobsource>Casting360</jobsource>
</job><job id="1370962">
<employer>Casting360</employer>
<title>Actresses Needed for &quot;Red Shore&quot;, Action Film</title>
<category>Acting</category>
<description>CASTING (non-union)
We are a New Independent company looking to shoot our first feature. We are currently looking to fill two Major roles.

Female/African American, Hispanic, Asian, Pacific Islander/ 5'5-5'10/ Age Late 30's-Early 40's.

Project description: A long standing feud between two best friends turned enemies escalates over a valuable Diamond on display in a New York City Museum. With the stakes high they each seek the help of both friends and strangers to settle their feud once and for all. 

Please note this is a non-paid project. 
Fight training will be provided for free. 

Please email including age and height in your e-mail.
Those selected will be invited to our audition.</description>
<postingdate>2016-10-03T14:18:20Z</postingdate>
<joburl>http://casting360.com/lgj/8886644624?jobid=1370962&amp;city=New+York&amp;state=NY</joburl>
<location>
<nation>USA</nation>
<city>New York</city>
<state>New York</state>
</location>
<jobsource>Casting360</jobsource>
</job>
</positionfeed>
```

Comment: Why is that stylesheet generic if you match on a particular element in a particular namespace like the `job` and additionally put the relative XPath expressions in a top level element? Which XSLT processor do you target and how deeply nested can the data be? What's wrong with writing `<xsl:apply-templates select="title, location/city"/>` instead of editing your column structure?

Comment: Good point.  Generic in the sense that to use the stylesheet, one would have to change the columns and the name of the node that contains the data ('job' in this case).  Perhaps it can be improved further.  I am working with SAXON.  Theoretically, the depth of the data doesn't matter (assuming getNodeValue works properly).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by using apply-templates?

Comment: Instead of setting up your column values you want to edit and process with `<xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">` you could as well edit an `<xsl:apply-templates select="title, location/city"/>`. Which version of Saxon is that, the commercial editions could even give you dynamic XPath evaluation if you really want to go that way.

Comment: I'm using Saxon-HE 9.7.0-10.  I think apply-templates would work, if there was a way to dynamically fill the select value.  Is there?

Comment: You don't need a leading `//` in a match pattern so patterns like `match="//*[local-name()=$containerNodeName]"` can be shortened to `match="*[local-name()=$containerNodeName]"`.

Comment: Also in XSLT 2.0 a single line `<xsl:value-of select="'Id', $columns/@header" separator="{$delimiter}"/>` could replace the nine lines of your template to generate the column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you could define your columns in a variable like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="columns" as="element()*">
    <column>title</column>
    <column>location/city</column>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then you can just iterate over them with a simple statement

```
<xsl:for-each select="$columns">
```

But the problem you may be having is that within this `xsl:for-each` you have changed context. You are no longer positioned on a `job` element, but the `column` element, and you don't want your expression to be relative to that. You really need to swap back to being on the job element, which you can do simply by setting a variable reference to the `job` element before the `xsl:for-each` and then using that as a parameter to the named template:

```
<xsl:template match="job">
   <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
   <xsl:variable name="job" select="." />
   <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
       <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
       <xsl:variable name="vXpathExpression" select="."/>
       <xsl:call-template name="getNodeValue">
           <xsl:with-param name="pCurrentNode" select="$job"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pExpression" select="$vXpathExpression"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

As for quoting the result; instead of doing just `xsl:value-of` simply call the `quote` template with the value as a parameter

```
 <xsl:when test="not(contains($pExpression, '/'))">
   <xsl:call-template name="quotevalue">
     <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$pCurrentNode/*[name()=$pExpression]" />
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:when>
```

EDIT: If you want a header row of column names, you would have to match the parent of the `job` node, and then just output the values of the $column variable

```
<xsl:template match="*[job]">
    <xsl:value-of select="$columns" separator="," />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Or maybe this if you didn't want the full path

```
<xsl:value-of select="$columns/(tokenize(., '/')[last()])" separator="," />
```

Or you could extend your `columns` variable to have the header text

```
<xsl:variable name="columns" as="element()*">
    <column header="Title">title</column>
    <column header="City">location/city</column>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then you would do this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$columns/@header" separator="," />
```

Comment: I now see how the for-each was the culprit - thanks! I am down to one last task: How do I generate the column names without using a <xsl:template> to match on a specific node?

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to show how you might do this.

Comment: Good stuff Tim!  Your suggestion for matching the parent of 'job' for the column headers is clashing with the way I am matching the 'job' nodes themselves.  I have defined <xsl:param name="containerNodeName" select="'job'"/> so that I could use <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()=$containerNodeName]"> to match the job nodes (where the column nodes exists).  I'd like to have 2 templates that are not hard-coded to any specific XML: a) 1 that matches and generates column names and b) 1 that matches and generates column data. Cant' seem to figure out two generic match values that don't clash.

Comment: You could possibly do `<xsl:template match="//*[*[local-name()=$containerNodeName]]">`, but feel free to ask a whole new question if you can't get it to work. Thanks!